# How can I shrink the size of my mono touch application

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios

I created a simple hello world mono touch (iPhone) application. However, its size is 5MB.

Is there a way to make it smaller?

Comment: Zip it?  Write it in Objective-C?

Comment: @Nick Veys, you are kidding yeah?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is from the mailing list post today:

> In addition to this thread, I wanted to give folks a heads up on
>   what we have been up to with MonoTouch and disk/memory usage.
>
> - New ARM optimizations.
>
>   In the upcoming version of MonoTouch, a new ARM optimization will
>     for example reduce mscorlib native code by 300k.  So it will go from
>     800k to 500k.   You can expect the same kind of savings in other
>     assemblies as well.
>
>   This was implemented by a technique that reuses many of the wrapper
>     functions that Mono uses to shared wrappers.
> - Enhanced Linker
>
>   The linker is improving, and it will no longer for example pull any
>     of Mono.Security.dll, unless you use the http stack.   This in the
>     example below will remove some 300k from the final distribution as
>     well.
>
>   The linker is still too conservative, and we will continue to enhance it to be more aggressive and remove more code.
> - In general
>
>   Since we started, one of our goals to ensure that we would have a
>     small footprint, so we invested significant time on our linker, and we
>     continue to invest in it.

Comment: MonoTouch 1.1 is now available and addresses this issue. See http://monotouch.net/Releases/MonoTouch_1.1

Answer (score 1):

Mono apps on the IPhone include the Mono runtime so you can't really get much smaller than 5mb. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444777/how-big-is-an-objective-c-iphone-app-vs-a-monotouch-app)

EDIT: As per Miguel's answer, it appears the minimum footprint is about to shrink considerably.

Comment: I am listening to Miguel's podcast and he says it should be possible

Comment: Miguel is the one who put Mono Touch together, so he may be the best person to ask about reducing Mono's footprint.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the linker options. Link SDK only or Link all assemblies.